# insert html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try using ajax after submitting the form to get another

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: $this.serialize(), 
                success: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                    document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(data.form1);
                }, 
                error: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
});
```

but on the page the html code is inserted as a string, how can this be fixed?

Comment: try `$("#my_form").html(data.form1)`. It should work

Comment: can you add a `console.log()` output for `data.form1` to your question, would help addressing the issue.

Comment: @NalinDobhal it works. I had it. but I get the form inside the form. and this interferes in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its look like your are replacing your subbmitting form, you can use jQuery .html() function to replace.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                data: $this.serialize(), 
                success: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                    //document.getElementById("my_form").replaceWith(data.form1); //remove this.
                   //add below code
                   var parent=$("#my_form").parent();
                   parent.html(data.form1);
                }, 
                error: function(data) 
                { console.log(data); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
});
```

Comment: this code ... parent.html('');  parent.html(data.form1);  ... simply causes two DOM mutations - the second one is the only one required - this will set the innerHTML of the element with the data.form1 - you don't need to empty the html of the element only to immediately replace it. The fewer times you manipulate the DOM - the better